# ng-src with ng-show not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I have appended `/File/` in `ng-src` which calls my Image source from database through Id. How to use use `ng-show`condition?

This is my code :

```
<img ng-src="/File/{{review.ProfileImage}}" class="media-object img-circle">
```

Anyone have a clue about this  ?

Comment: simple add `ng-show="somecondition"` in your img tag

Comment: dont understand it, when you need to use ng-show?

Comment: Hi Álvaro Touzón, I want to use ng-show when image is not null, if there's no image then I'll show default image from system.

Comment: try to use ng-if

Comment: @Dixit Can you share code sample. That will be more helpful for me.

Comment: Here's the code what I tried. <img ng-src="/File/{{review.ProfileImage}}" class="media-object img-circle" ng-show = "/File/{{review.ProfileImage == ' '}}">

Comment: _ng-show = "review.ProfileImage!=''"_ Simply check the value of the variable _review.ProfileImage_

Comment: no need to use `ng-show` in your case [you can set alternate image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92819/5621827) using js only

Comment: @jitender it is OK, but we still want to avoid doing extra call to our back-end, so `ngIf` will work better in this case.

Comment: then do other stuff like `set show/hide` inside `onError` mathod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use interpolation inside [`ngShow` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow). Just use a simple condition to check your `review.ProfileImage` field:

```
<img ng-src="/File/{{review.ProfileImage}}" ng-show="review.ProfileImage" class="media-object img-circle"/>
```

For your case I would recommend using [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) instead of [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) (in this case `img` will be removed from the DOM and you will not hit your back-end with image source request).